# How can i stop ajax request and then continue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I stop Ajax request and then continue, for example if status code response is `403`, stop this request and prompt user if he wants to continue  or not.

```
$.ajax({
  url: t,
  method: "GET",
  async: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
 if (xhr.status == 403) {
      //how can i stop this request call prompt if click ok then
      var check = prompt("Do you want this request?");

      if (check) {
        //success code
      }
    }

  }
}); //ajax
```

Comment: What do you mean with stop this request? The request has already been executed here.

Comment: The server returned 403 error, where do you want to go from there?? It doesn't make sense

Comment: i mean from where i can stop it

Comment: It is already stopped - You're in the `complete` callback!

Comment: you are in `complete` function, and `403` mean that your request is done and the server return a result then closed the connection, you have to do another request in this case.

Comment: i want to stop this request before success

Comment: so how can i stop it before complete?

Comment: It sound like the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because none of this is making sense

Comment: i have edited the code

Comment: OK, so we have the currently unknown and unimplemented "success code" - In plain words, what exactly should happen there? Note that if the server returned 403 code than it's  a **failed** ajax request (That's why you will not get to the `success` callback in case of a 403 response)

Comment: can i get the response data in the complete callback ?

Comment: No, you can't `:)` that's the whole point of [403 response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) - The server says "You can't get a response, because you don't have permissions to view it"

Comment: what about that

 If an error occurred: jqXHR.always(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { });
And otherwise:

jqXHR.always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { });

Comment: I wish I could help, I really do, but unfortunately there are not enough details about the nature of the request (From both the client and the server side perspectives). Maybe someone else could help, but I suggest that you [read](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/403-forbidden-error) a bit about 403 errors (Google for something like "how to fix 403 forbidden javascript")

Comment: bro i don't need the 403 unauthorized response data i just wanna check this status if it, stop the request until you authorized

Comment: I see. So maybe [this](https://cypressnorth.com/programming/global-ajax-error-handling-with-jquery/) or [this](https://www.viralpatel.net/jquery-ajax-handling-unauthenticated-request-ajax/) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$.ajax( ...params... )
     .then(
           function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
                 alert("Success: " +  data);
                 // initiate next sequential operation
           },
           function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                 // initiate next sequential operation
           });
```

Answer

```
function requestT(t){


$.ajax({
        url:t,    
        method:"GET",
        async: true,
        xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
         }
     }).then(function(data,textstatus,xhr) {

           //your code....
  },

            function(xhr,text,error){


                   var x = prompt("do you want to continue if YES enter 1?");
                   if(x == 1){
                       console.log("reload Request...");
                        requestT(t);
                   }

               }

            );//ajax

        }//func request
```